# Hadoop input SequenceFile of matrix multiplication

Tags: hadoop, matrix, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I was running the MapReduce Matrix Multiplication.java program found at this site http://www.norstad.org/matrix-multiply/index.html.
(source code can be seen at the end of the site)

When I executed it, it said the input was not a SequenceFile

My input file is recently `inputA.txt` and it looks like this

```
A,0,1,1.0
A,0,2,2.0
A,0,3,3.0
A,0,4,4.0
A,1,0,5.0
A,1,1,6.0
A,1,2,7.0
A,1,3,8.0
A,1,4,9.0
```

with the format: MatrixName, row, col, element
And of course, it didn't work.

I really want to run this source code because of its algorithm. So how can I generate the right SequenceFile in this case?
Can I generate it from the .txt file I've already have?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the included test code (at the link you provided) in `TestMatrixMultiply` should give you something to work with.

I've pulled out the relevant bits to get you started. This (untested) code should create two sequence files (see `testIdentity()`).

You can see in the `writeMatrix` method how it creates a SequenceFile and the structure used, which i assume is the same the actual mapreduce job works with.

You could extend this code to read your text file, populate the 2D matrix array correctly and then write a Sequence file.

```
public class TestMatrixMultiply {

    private static final String DATA_DIR_PATH = "/tmp/MatrixMultiply";
    private static final String INPUT_PATH_A = DATA_DIR_PATH + "/A";
    private static final String INPUT_OATH_B = DATA_DIR_PATH + "/B";

    private static Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    private static FileSystem fs;

    public static void writeMatrix (int[][] matrix, 
              int rowDim, int colDim, String pathStr) throws IOException {

        Path path = new Path(pathStr);
        SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(fs, conf, path, 
        MatrixMultiply.IndexPair.class, IntWritable.class, 
        SequenceFile.CompressionType.NONE);
        MatrixMultiply.IndexPair indexPair = new MatrixMultiply.IndexPair();
        IntWritable el = new IntWritable();
        for (int i = 0; i < rowDim; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colDim; j++) {
                int v = matrix[i][j];
                if (v != 0) {
                    indexPair.index1 = i;
                    indexPair.index2 = j;
                    el.set(v);
                    writer.append(indexPair, el);
                }
            }
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args);
        fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        fs.mkdirs(new Path(DATA_DIR_PATH));

        A = new int[][] { {1,0}, {0,1}};
        B = new int[][] { {1,0}, {0,1}};
        writeMatrix(A, 2, 2, INPUT_PATH_A);
        writeMatrix(B, 2, 2, INPUT_OATH_B);
    }
}
```

You should note that this approach will be ok for small amounts of data. Once you start hitting any sort of scale you would probably want to write a mapreduce job that takes your text file as input and writes out a sequence file.